# Get jquery error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on("focus",'.select2-selection--multiple',function(){
    $(".select2-search__field").focus();
});
```

when i am using this getting error "too much recursion" in firefox and "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in chrome.

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 100px;">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
            <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

this is my html actually i am using selec2 plugin and try to focus on that
when i press tab.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `.select2-search_field` is *inside* the `.select2-selection--multiple` field and that the event is bubbling up the DOM and hitting this handler - hence recursion. You probably need to trap the `focus` event on the inner element and apply `stopPropagation` to the event. Seeing your HTML would help.

Comment: I think the same as @RoryMcCrossan it'd be great to see your html to prove it though.

Comment: thanks for help and yes is it in .select2-selection--multiple and i had used stopPropagation but getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

As Rory mentioned, you have to prevent the event from bubbling up:

```
$(document).on("focus", '.select2-search__field', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("focus", '.select2-selection--multiple', function() {
  $(".select2-search__field").focus();
});
```